upload file image to server using activity result launcher
I am currently working on a task that involves taking a picture and uploading it to the server. The data sent to the server needs to be in multipart form-data format, and I need to create a file from the URI obtained by the ActivityResultLauncher. However, the URI seems to be a fake path, and the file created from the URI does not exist.
How can I obtain the real path from the URI obtained by the ActivityResultLauncher?
Update: Here is my code
First i define this in AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
        android:authorities="com.tgddssss.projectcf.fileProvider"
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

    </provider>

@xml/file_paths:
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path
    name="camera_photos"
    path="."/>

After that i create new Uri by this function:
fun createUri(): Uri {
    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault())
    val currentTimeString = dateFormat.format(Date(currentTime))
    val fileName = "photo_$currentTimeString.jpg"
    val file = File(requireActivity()?.applicationContext?.filesDir, fileName)
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireActivity().applicationContext,
        "com.tgddssss.projectcf.fileProvider",
        file
    )
}

Using this function to create ActivityResultLauncher for Uri
fun registerPictureLauncher(imageUri: Uri?): ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> {
    return registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        ActivityResultCallback {
            try {
                if (it) {
                    val file = File(imageUri.toString())
                    Log.d("TAG","${file.exists()}")
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    )

}

And some permission check by Permission Dispactcher...

You will not try to get a 'real' path from that uri as you can use the uri to upload the file or read it contents.

But... If you let a Camera app take a picture you would start with a real path and use that with FileProvider for the Camera app. So just use the original file path. Unclear what you do.

@blackapps I just updated the issue, can you look over my code plss!!!

Code incomplete. Where do you call and use createUri()? And how and where do you call registerPictureLauncher()?

val file = File(requireActivity()?.applicationContext?.filesDir.... Well file contains the path you are after. That is the real path you started with.

Agreed, if the file exists at the location identified by file, that is the path to use. For situations where you only have a Uri, the duplicate question points out a few ways to use OkHttp/Retrofit to handle your uploads without needing a "real path".

@blackapps sorry about slow reply. So if i sent that file to server, could it be completed?
